# Flutter text not rendering correctly in some cases

Tags: flutter

I am developing a flutter app to display speed itself. But sometime, the speed isn't rendered correctly in the UI. This doesn't happen always but happens say 5-10% of the time.
I tried to add another text field, with lesser size below it(just to debug), and the same text renders there correctly.

> 2 screenshots - One correct and one with the bug

[image]

[image]

I am using a column widget to display the text and this is how I am building the children list:

```
List<Widget> children = [];
children.add(Container(
    child: Text(listenerSpeedText,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightGreen, fontSize: 100.00)),
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.00)));

children.add(Text(
  'digitalSpeed: ' + listenerSpeedText,
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.red,
    fontSize: 25.00,
  ),
));
return children;
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am not sure what is going on. Do I need to give extra width or height to container?

Comment: Couple of questions for you. Have you tested if the same thing happens when using RichText instead of Text widget. How are you generating the number to be displayed? I'm wondering if there is too much for a single thread.

Comment: No I haven't tested RichText yet but I can try that. For the second question, yes in a thread I am using geolocator api to get position and then calculate speed from the returned position. And I am calling the method recursively so I would say a lot of work is going on in that thread. What I don't understand is why the second text displau gets updated but the first one doesn't.

Comment: Are you familiar with Isolates? I'm fairly new to Flutter but I have found through my own app and other people's comments on stackoverflow that anything that requires a lot of processing you should do in a separate thread so that the UI does not hang.